# Categories in a categorical predictor disappearing in my multinomial logistic regression model (R)

Tags: r

I'm running a multinomial logistic regression model including several categorical predictors, one of these predictors `Region` has four categories, yet, none of them is shown in the model summary output.

I get the following results:

```
multinom(formula = agegp ~ diaggp + Sex + Region, data = mydata)

(Intercept)     diaggp2nd    diaggp3rd      Sex         Region

31-50    -0.9759359    0.02334910   -0.08953634   0.2415160   0.0006931416

18-30    -2.6073819   -0.48572713   -0.64507585   0.3100420   0.0005030398
```

As you can see, Region categories aren't displayed

Would greatly appreciate any advice on this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO! Can you provide us with a reproducible example, i.e., a small working code with the data you used? If you have doubts, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Check that `Region` is actually a factor.  The result you got is what you'd see if `Region` was numeric.

Comment: Thank you. I did check it and it is a factor.

Comment: Thank you problem has been fixed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.